# How to Get solidity code from abi key and contract address

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I have an issue I lost my solidity code but I have the abi key and contract address of that code. so I just wanna know if I can get back my solidity smart contract code from the abi key and contract address? if yes then how do I get it in remix?

Answer (score 0):

ABI JSON and bytecode (deployed on an address) are derived from a source code. It's not possible to fully reverse the operation and derive source code from ABI and bytecode.

There are decompilers, such as Panoramix [integrated](https://etherscan.io/bytecode-decompiler) into Etherscan, that allow you to decimpile the bytecode into pseudocode. However they are not perfect and often not able to decompile some functions or generate overly complicated pseudocode for a simple operation.